# World's best chef

Tags: riddle

Your friend received a resume and have you only pieces of it. Who is it that the resume describes?

[image]

Text version of the words:

> World's Best Chef 
>  Skills 
>  Highest ranking in 
>  Vegetables
>   per 
>  min 
>  Cooking more than 
>  Time 
>  Absolute perfect
>   
>  Raw 
>  me 
>  Save money 
>  no utensils 
>  Info 
>  Not
>   available 
>  nights 
>  Author 
>  Yoga 
>  books 
>  References
>   
>  Vyv 
>  Me 
>  Roo

*Extra Credit: who are the 3 references?*

Clue:

> This riddle is getting really old, but never as old as the answer.

Comment: can you please check the answers and let us know the correct answer

Comment: Neither of the answers include the "Author ... Yoga ... books" clue.  Both are wrong. :(

Answer (score 1):

The riddle is describing the:

> Trees.

Explanation:

> Highest ranking in **vegetables** *(trees make vegetables)*. Cooking more than (...) time. *(trees are cooking since they're created on earth)*. Save money ... utensils. *(Trees don't need any utensils to cook)*. Not available nights. *(Trees can't cook at night)*.

References:

> Vyv might me vyvanse, Roo might be roots, .

I don't have any idea for me

Answer (score 0):

Resume Riddle describes:

> **Root Vegetables** (Potato's, carrots, onions, garlic, celery root (or celeriac), turmeric, radishes, and ginger etc.)

Words Explanation:

> World Best Chef (Every one can use) 
>  Skills and High ranking (Don't need at all)
>  Cooking more than a min/vegetable (If we want to bake it like Potato) 
>  Raw absolutely perfect for cooking and (No need of Utensils and save cooking time, just wash with water and can eat)

and

> Not Available night means (We shouldn't eat Root vegetables at night like Potatoes have a high glycemic index, which means they contain enough sugar to spike energy levels rather quickly. When energy levels spike, insulin also spikes)

and

> Author: Yoga -> **http://www.yogajournal.com/lifestyle/roast-up-some-roots**

References:

> VYV- Vyvlander land is generally fertile and often used for farming, especially of vegetables.
>  Roo and ME refers same - Root vegetables